# Populating rails Database from Amazon RDS data

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-rds, rails-postgresql

I currently am working on an inventory application(rails 4.0 on Heroku using PostgreSQL). I also have a database that tracks my sales on Amazon RDS using Sql Server 2008. I'd like to figure out a way to access the RDS on demand (click of a button, or on certain intervals) to pull certain fields from RDS to my rails app database.

data sample:

RDS:Salesdb

Order number, amazon id, ebay id, newegg id, First Name, Last Name, Product, Quantity, Price, product weight

Rails: Orders

Order number, product id, quantity

I'm not sure if there is more specific information needed in order to answer this question, so let me know what you need and i'll update the question.

Thanks for your help!